# How can I find an existing node and then link it to another node?

Tags: jaseci

Would something like this work?

Basically what I am trying to do is to link an edge to a node but in return linking the node to an existing node but I need to query the node to find it to link it.

```
here -[people_link(id="123")]-> node::person(name==w);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work in version 1.4 of Jaseci. Try somethign like

```
here +[people_link(id="123")]+> node::person(name==w);
```